# Tensorflow Keras Model subclassing -- call function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am experimenting with self supervised learning using tensorflow. The example code I'm running can be found in the Keras examples website. [This is the link](https://keras.io/examples/vision/nnclr/) to the NNCLR example. The Github link to download the code can be [found here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/nnclr.py). While I have no issues running the examples, I am running into issues when I try to save the pretrained or the finetuned model using `model.save()`.
The error I'm getting is this:

```
 f"Model {model} cannot be saved either because the input shape is not "
 ValueError: Model <__main__.NNCLR object at 0x7f6bc0f39550> cannot be saved either 
 because the input shape is not available or because the forward pass of the model is
 not defined. To define a forward pass, please override `Model.call()`. 
 To specify an input shape, either call `build(input_shape)` directly, or call the model on actual data using `Model()`, `Model.fit()`, or `Model.predict()`. 
 If you have a custom training step, please make sure to invoke the forward pass in train step through  
`Model.__call__`, i.e. `model(inputs)`, as opposed to `model.call()`.
```

I am unsure how to override the Model.call() method.  Appreciate some help.

Comment: Which part do you not understand? How to override a method? Just define a `__call__()` method in your subclass. You can try just calling parent's method from within, something like `def __call__(self): super().__call__()`. If that doesn't work you might need to manually define the method as per instructions above.

Comment: i've tried defining the call method as well as specifying an input shape and calling model.build() but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve model saving in such cases is to override the `save` (or `save_weights`) method in the `keras.Model` class. In your case, first initialize the finetune model in the `NNCLR` class. And next, override the `save` method for it. FYI, in this way, you may also able to use `ModelCheckpoint` API.

---

As said, define the finetune model in the `NNCLR` model class and override the `save` method for it.

```
class NNCLR(keras.Model):
    def __init__(...):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        self.finetuning_model = keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
                self.classification_augmenter,
                self.encoder,
                layers.Dense(10),
            ],
            name="finetuning_model",
        )
    
    ...

    def save(
        self, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, 
        save_format=None, signatures=None, options=None
    ):
        self.finetuning_model.save(
            filepath=filepath,
            overwrite=overwrite,
            save_format=save_format,
            options=options,
            include_optimizer=include_optimizer,
            signatures=signatures
        )

model = NNCLR(...)
model.compile
model.fit
```

Next, you can do

```
model.save('finetune_model') # SavedModel format
finetune_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('finetune_model', compile=False)

'''
NNCLR code example: Evaluate sections
"A popular way to evaluate a SSL method in computer vision or 
for that fact any other pre-training method as such is to learn 
a linear classifier on the frozen features of the trained backbone 
model and evaluate the classifier on unseen images."
'''
for layer in finetune_model.layers:
    if not isinstance(layer, layers.Dense):
        layer.trainable = False

finetune_model.summary() # OK
finetune_model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="acc")],
)
finetune_model.fit
```